# Counting and summing in r

Tags: r

My data looks like this:

[image]

did is not unique. hhid has all unique ids.L1,L2 and L3 consists of 1s and 0s and if L2 is 1 then it has been categorised into A B and C.

The output required is like this:
[image]

The did has now become unique in the 2nd image.The count of 1s is mentioned in L1_count, L2_count and L3_count.Further L2_count is further categorised into L2Type_A L2Type_B and L2Type_C. The L_amt is summed up based on hhid.
Need support for this.

Comment: Can you share data using dput() function? It's not possible to recreate your data in R if you share it as a pic.

Comment: Have posted the answer, see if that works for you.

Comment: df<-data.frame(did=c(209,209,206,206,206,207,207,214,215,215,216,217),                         hhid=c(5668,5595,4724,4856,4730,2381,6317,5513,6459,6871,6878,6872),
L1=c(1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0),
L2=c(0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0),
L2_type=c(0,0,A,C,A,0,0,B,B,C,C,0),
L3=c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1),
lL_amt=c(20000,20000,14000,14000,14000,12700,27000,16000,10000,14000,12000,5000))

Comment: Have made the changes, see if that works

Comment: @Rahul Edit your post to add the example don't add it as a comment. Also make sure that your example actually runs. The one which you have shared in the comment does not.

Comment: Sorry Ronak.I am still learning.Next time I will share it in proper format.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% group_by(did) %>% 
+   summarise(hhid_count = n(), L1_count = sum(L1), L2_count = sum(L2), L2_Type_A = sum('A' == L2_type),
+             L2_Type_B = sum('B' == L2_type), L2_Type_C = sum('C' == L2_type), L3_count = sum(L3), L_amt_sum = sum(lL_amt))
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 7 x 9
    did hhid_count L1_count L2_count L2_Type_A L2_Type_B L2_Type_C L3_count L_amt_sum
  <dbl>      <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <int>     <int>     <int>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1   206          3        0        3         2         0         1        0     42000
2   207          2        1        0         0         0         0        1     39700
3   209          2        2        0         0         0         0        0     40000
4   214          1        0        1         0         1         0        0     16000
5   215          2        0        2         0         1         1        0     24000
6   216          1        0        1         0         0         1        0     12000
7   217          1        0        0         0         0         0        1      5000
>
```

Data used:

```
structure(list(did = c(209, 209, 206, 206, 206, 207, 207, 214, 
215, 215, 216, 217), hhid = c(5668, 5595, 4724, 4856, 4730, 2381, 
6317, 5513, 6459, 6871, 6878, 6872), L1 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), L2 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), 
    L2_type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    L3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), lL_amt = c(20000, 
    20000, 14000, 14000, 14000, 12700, 27000, 16000, 10000, 14000, 
    12000, 5000)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L
))
```

Comment: Are you running the code as I've given above? If you not getting that line means you are not grouping by did.